# Linux -> linux remote X login/desktop

Tags: xorg, remote, xforwarding, vpn

What are the (best) solutions for remote desktop in linux? Ideally I'd like to be able to be able to log in to a remote X (KDE) session without even logging into my local machine. Maybe if I could have a remote X session forwarded to a different virtual terminal session so I can switch back and forth between local and remote with Ctrl + alt + n?

This is going to be over the internet via a VPN, so data-light solutions would be best =]

Comment: I too would like to know. This would be quite useful.

Comment: X2go. It is safe enough to simply have a local system service that fires up an Xserver with X2go as it's only running program. If the local client is a stupid terminal without a hard drive and especially without critical data there is nothing wrong with such an approach

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think you might be looking for xpra. You will have to log in to an X Server locally to use it, but you should be able to set it up so your local X Server has a seperate workspace which connects to and mirrors an xpra workspace hosted remotely.

http://jkwarren.info/blogs/index.php/2009/09/09/favorite-new-toy-xpra

Comment: That's pretty cool, but it looks like it does its attaching over plain ssh. There's no way that will be fast enough not on the LAN

Comment: @Falmarri it's plenty fast and supports many other modes than ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that simple X forwarding will be too slow for what you want to do, so you'll have to choose between other protocols like VNC (thereis plenty of implementations), RDP (rdesktop) or NX. I would recommend NX as it is based on X, is very fast and even provides sound and file transfer. FreeNX is easy to setup and as it is based on X (just compressed and sshed during transfer) you should be able to integrate it like you want to your locale machine.

Comment: +1 for nx technology. Although I stopped using it because of some odd issues, it was generally great.