# Is there anyway to run gnome desktop via a remote x window ssh tunnel?

Tags: gnome, x11, remote, ssh-tunneling

I'd like to run the DE remotely in a window of it's own on my local workstation. When I tried the naive `gnome-session` from an x-window tunnel it tried to takeover my local xfce desktop, got as far as changing the wallpaper before crashing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux -> linux remote X login/desktop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/linux-linux-remote-x-login-desktop)

Comment: not necessarily a duplicate, but your/my answer is here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46861/cant-get-gnome-session-working-over-ssh

Answer (score 2):

I am quite fond of NX. There are two sources for NX: [OpenNX](http://opennx.net/) and [Nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/)'s NX. Nomachine's implementation is commercial yet free for Linux and Solaris - free as in [beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre). This software tunnels X over SSH, and provides an "RDP-ish" experience, with the entire desktop available in a window.